# Passing shared_ptr by reference

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "ctor called\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {

        std::cout << "dtor called\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::thread thread1([]{
        std::shared_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
        std::thread thread2([](std::shared_ptr<A>& arg){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            std::cout << "use_count: " << arg.use_count() << std::endl;
        },ptr);
        thread2.detach();
        std::cout << "thread1 quitting\n";
    });
    thread1.detach();
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

And got this result:

```
ctor called
thread1 quitting
use_count: 1
dtor called
```

However, I expected this to happen:

```
ctor called
thread1 quitting
dtor called
use_count: 0
```

Because I think passing the shared_ptr by reference won't increase its ref count, thus the managed object will be destroyed as soon as thread1 gets out of scope. Could you tell me why I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your lambda to take a `shared_ptr` reference, but the constructor of `std::thread` copies all arguments by default.

If you step through the destructors being called, you'll see that it's use count is briefly 2, before the original is destroyed.

To pass the shared_ptr as a reference, you can use `std::ref`:

`std::thread thread2([]{/*...*/}, std::ref(ptr));`

This will give you the expected behavior of `ptr` going out of scope, which means you invoke undefined behavior when you access it anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I get my expected result. And could you explain a bit about what template magic std::ref() do? I tried `std::shared_ptr<A>& ref = ptr;` and pass the ref to thread2. It's also useless.

Comment: Using `std::ref` will cause undefined behavior, since the shared pointer is going out of scope, and using that reference would be bad.

Comment: @DaveS Thanks for your reminding. I'm just testing out thread-safety of shared_ptr...

Comment: @melak47:  `std::ref` doesn't interact with weak counts at all.  It creates a structure which has an implicit conversion to a reference.  You're still using a reference to the now-destroyed `shared_ptr<A>`.  The fact that the memory might still be there or have sane values is irrelevant.